# How to change cell properties by referring to its dynamic name range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, range

When named range is a static cell or a range I'd refer to it by its name and change cell property like so:

`Worksheets("Manual_Input").Range("test_range").Interior.Color = vbYellow`

Unfortunately, when named cell/range has formula in it, for example, `=ROUND((Manual_Input!$F$17/1000),1)`

I cannot seem to actually refer to $F$17 and change its properties. Running above statement returns 'Application-defined or object-defined error', although can be accessed by running:

`ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range")`

which returns following:

`=ROUND((Manual_Input!$F$17/1000),1)`

I can even evaluate this named range by running:
`Worksheets("Manual_Input").Evaluate("test_range")`

which returns result of the formula

`=ROUND((Manual_Input!$F$17/1000),1)`

How do I get to the range F17 by its name in VBA?

Comment: What about `Range("F17")`? Or check `ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersToRange.Address`?

Comment: I want to refer to F17 by its name. ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersToRange.Address returns 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersToRange.Addres` will return a string with the address of test_range. You need to use it as the name of a range, or set it up.

Comment: It does return a string with the address when named range is as simple as this for example '=Manual_Input!$F$17', but when it has formula in it, like so, '=ROUND((Manual_Input!$F$17/1000),1), it returns 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

Comment: Just to clarify, is it the case that `named_range` does not actually **Refer to:** `F17` but rather that it **Refers to:** a formula that happens to contain a cell reference `F17`?

Comment: The problem is that a named range is meant to refer to a *range*; defining it as a value gets you a value, not a range.

Comment: What you have is not a "named range", but a just a "name".

Answer (score 0):

`Split(ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersTo, "$")(1) & Split(Split(ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersTo, "$")(2), ",")(0)` should return the string you are looking for.

`ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersTo` will return always in english the formula you applied to that range, as string. so you need extra function to split and get the text part you want.

In my case, i created a name like yours, referring to cell G9:

[image]

My code:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim vName As Name
Set vName = Application.ThisWorkbook.Names("test_range")

Debug.Print vName.RefersTo 'string with reference in english, not local

Debug.Print Split(vName.RefersTo, "$")(1) & Split(Split(vName.RefersTo, "$")(2), ",")(0) 'cell inside that string

Set vName = Nothing


End Sub
```

My output:

[image]

You'll need to use other functions like MID,LEFT,RIGHT, SPLIT to get exactly the text part you want to isolate.

Comment: LEFT(Split(ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersTo, "$")(1) & Split(Split(ActiveWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersTo, "$")(2), ",")(0),2) returns J2. This super clunky way, I already regret using named ranges, but thank you very much.